# Incremental Crawl not running as scheduled (Sharepoint 2013)

Tags: sharepoint-server, crawling

I scheduled my incremental crawl to run every 5 minutes. However, it is not running. It should crawl by 5:55pm, but it didn't. Any advice?

[image]

Thanks!

This is the settings page.
[image]

Comment: Can you share the screen of content source's setting page where crawl schedule selected?

Comment: Added. Please check again.

Comment: that's weird, did you see any thing in the crawl log? or enable the verbose on search then check the ULS logs at the time when it skip. Looks like it confused...can you change the schedule to some other timings and test it.

Comment: There is not even a log created.

Comment: did you change the schedule from 5 min to some thing different and also can you trace the skipping pattern?

Comment: Yeah I did... And there is no skipping pattern. Because it's not running at all.

Comment: did you find any solution to this issue?we are facing same issue on our SP2013 environment

Answer (score 2):

Just got this one fixed for me. The crawl were scheduled but they would never start - the dates would get updated.

Background: we have 2 search servers, SP timer service (services.msc) were started in both. Tried restarting and cleaning the Cache folder but that didn't help. Problem started happening when I changed the scheduled time. There were no errors on ULS or event viewer

How it was fixed:

1. Went **Manage services on server** (Central Admin)
2. **SharePoint Server Search** service was stopped in one of the servers
3. The only way to start that was using PowerShell on the server that had the service stopped. As seen in [this Microsoft page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/start-spenterprisesearchserviceinstance?view=sharepoint-ps)

   Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Local | Start-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance